# Ruby - How to filter SQLite rows based on column conditions

Tags: ruby, sqlite

I have a variable `session[:pet_profile_tags]` that returns an array like `["adult", "activity_low", "overweight"].`

I then have an SQLite database, called balto.db, which contains the table pet_tips. That table contains 2 columns, "ID" (Integer) and "C1_inclusion" (VARCHAR).

For each row of the pet_tips table, I need to check if the value contained in the `C1_inclusion` column contains one of the values of the `session[:pet_profile_tags]` array variable. If that is the case, I need to check the row's ID and store it inside another array variable, named `pet_tips`.

I tried the below code but I am getting the following error: `TypeError - no implicit conversion of String into Integer: index.rb:428:in '[]'` , line 428 being `if (session[:pet_profile_tags].include?(row["C1_inclusion"].to_s))`

```
        # Assign pet tips
        pet_tips = []

        # Query the pet_tips table
        db = SQLite3::Database.open "balto.db"
        rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM pet_tips")

        # Iterate through each row of the table
        rows.each do |row|
          # Check if the row matches the C1_inclusion column
          if (session[:pet_profile_tags].include?(row["C1_inclusion"].to_s))
            # If the row matches, add the ID to the pet_tips array
            pet_tips << row["ID"]
          end
        end
        session[:pet_tips] = pet_tips
        db.close
```

I have been stuck for hours, any help would be really appreciated!

First I tried returning the value of the session[:pet_profile_tags] variable to make sure I was getting the correct array. Then, I made sure to check that the different column and variable names where correctly referenced in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Error

Your error is here: `row["C1_inclusion"]`

- `row` is an `Array` of values in column order e.g. `[1,"adult"]`.
- `Array#[]` expects an `Integer` (index) but you are calling it with a `String` ("C1_inclusion")

### Solutions

To solve this you can

**Option 1:**
Use `Integer` indexes based on column order

```
if (session[:pet_profile_tags].include?(row[1]))
  pet_tips << row[0]
end
```

**Option 2:** convert the row to `Hash`:

Always:

```
db = SQLite3::Database.open "balto.db"
db.results_as_hash
rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM pet_tips")
rows.each do |row|
  if (session[:pet_profile_tags].include?(row["C1_inclusion"]))
```

Just for this loop:

```
rows.each_hash do |row|
  if (session[:pet_profile_tags].include?(row["C1_inclusion"]))
```

**Option 3:** Query just the data you want.

```
# Query the pet_tips table
db = SQLite3::Database.open "balto.db"
session[:pet_tips] = db.prepare("SELECT ID FROM pet_tips WHERE pet_tips.C1_inclusion IN (?)")
  .execute!(session[:pet_profile_tags].map {|s| "'#{s}'"}.join(","))
  .flatten
db.close
```

This uses `session[:pet_profile_tags]` as a WHERE condition against `pet_tips.C1_inclusion` and assumes you have control over this variable (e.g. does not perform escaping)

Comment: Many thanks for the super clear answer, it worked like a charm (I used option 1)! Really appreciate it!